# Django 'CharField' object has no attribute split

Tags: django, split

i am creating an website where a user can search for recipes by their ingredients. I wish that when a user finally see recipe, ingredients there would be splited with ', ' in view. for now it is just space. I tried to do this in my model, but they i get error as in title 
 - 'CharField' object has no attribute split.

Models:

```
from django.db import models


class Ingredient(models.Model):

  ingredient_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  igredient_name1 = ingredient_name.split(', ')


  def __str__(self):
    return self.ingredient_name1



class Recipe(models.Model):

  recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  preparation = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.recipe_name
```

template:

```
<div>
    <h1><a href="/">Drink drank drunk</a></h1>
</div>


{% for drink in results %}
  <div>
    <p>{{ drink.recipe_name }}</p>
    <p>Preparation: {{ drink.preparation }}</p>
    <p>Ingredients:
    {% for ingredient in drink.ingredients.all %}
      {{ingredient.ingredient_name}}
    {% endfor %}
    </p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

view:

```
def drink_list(request):
    template = "drinks/drink_list.html"
    return render(request, template)



def search_results(besos):

    query = besos.GET.get('q')
    q = Q()
    for queries in query.split(', '):
        q |= (Q(ingredients__ingredient_name__icontains=queries))
    results = Recipe.objects.filter(q)

    template = "drinks/search_results.html"
    context = {
        'results' : results,
    }
    return render(besos, template, context)
```

Comment: Thats known because there is no ingredient at the moment, you have to override the `save` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some mess understanding what is needed to accomplish it seems that the solution is just to add the desired comma into the template, modifying the forloop as follows:

```html
{% for ingredient in drink.ingredients.all %}} 
   {{ingredient.ingredient_name}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, it has not helped. :(  ingredients are still displayed without comma.

Comment: Have you applied the change to your template?

Comment: Yes, i have edited both template and model, but the result is the same us before

Comment: Ok, I missunderstood your question, If now I understood it well you have a field that it's value is currently space separated, something like "whiskey lemon tonic" and so on, and you want it to be a comma separated value like "whiskey,lemon,tonic", is this right?

Comment: yes, exactly. but i still can not figure out why your solution does not work. it looks good hmm

Comment: Just before my last comment I've edited my solution, now it will work, take a look at the `save` method since it will convert the space separated values to comma separated ones in your DB and maybe you don't want this., but some caveats comes to my mind, what if you currently have an ingredient like "lemon juice"? it is space separated but is just an ingredient, after splitting it will become two different ones "lemon,juice"

Comment: What a mess, sorry for that, a simple question to propose you a final solution. Do you want your ingredients in your DB to be stored as comma separated or keep as a space separated values?

Comment: now it looks like that ingredients: lemon lemon juice apple honey i wish that user can see ingredients: lemon, lemon juice, apple, honey

Comment: Ok, check my edited solution, It will work except in the case of "lemon juice" since we cannot know that "lemon juice" is an ingredient, it will show lemon,juice as two separated items since there is an space (your current "separator") between those

Comment: It actually work only for „lemon juice” , i mean it put comma between words, if there is few, in one ingredient. so f.e. if i have „honey, apple, lemon juice, coca cola, ananas” then i get „honey apple lemon, juice coca, cola ananas”

Comment: So, your ingredients are currently comma separated, check my last edit (just changed de property in the Model)

Comment: they are not. only one ingredient which contains words was separated with comma. i have updated to this what you wrote with split(',') and now there is no coma at all displayed.

Comment: I'm so confused, can U post your RAW data please?

Comment: Can it be as simple as doing this in your template? `{% for ingredient in drink.ingredients.all %}}{{ingredient.ingredient_name}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Hi Gabriel! Yes it is working! and in addition it does not separate one ingredient with two words  "coca cola" with comma! :) i am going to analyze it deeper, but thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: Great! I've edited the solution for future references from the community, and again, sorry for the mess up understanding your needs!